# mysql_num_rows() returns zero

Tags: php, mysql

```
<form action = "index.php" method = "post">
username : <input type = "text" name = "uname" /><br>
password : <input type = "text" name = "pass" /><br>
submit : <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){echo $_SESSION['id'];}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if ($_POST['submit'] == 'submit'){

$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$db = "davidedwardcakes";
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'wtfiwwu');
$db_connect = mysql_selectdb($db, $connect);
if(!$db_connect){echo 'no';}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE uname ='$uname' AND pass = '$pass'";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connect);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){//echo 'index failed'; var_dump($result);}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){echo $row['uname']
 . "<br>";

session_start();
echo '<a href = "test.php">peruse</a>';
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];}}

else{echo 'lol'; var_dump($query);}}
```

Whenever I want to login, i get the error: 
    string 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname ='brown' AND pass = 'kenji''    (length=61)

meaning that theres a problem with my $query. If I remove the $pass query from $query it works fine but doesn't when it is included. Can anybody help please.

Comment: Huh? Why does that mean there's a problem with your query? That's your `var_dump` code.

Comment: That's not an error. That's your `var_dump($query);` code.

Comment: 1. Don't store passwords as plain text. 2. Don't use `mysql_*` functions; they're deprecated. 3. Your code is wide open to SQL injection...

Comment: If you really had a SQL syntax error (as the question title states) the query would not even run.

Comment: remove `var_dump($query)` from your code.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: @BenM how do I store passwords then

Comment: do you have column called `pass` ? or maybe its `upass` ??

Comment: @echo, i do, and i stored it with varchar

Comment: Try this and see what error is `$result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());` instead of yours

Comment: my connection is working perfectly because when i just send query for uname alone, it works fine but if i add the pass that's when it doesn't work out. I dud the vardump to check the issue and thats it. The problem is the double quotes at kenji in the var_dump. My question is how do i get mysql not to include this in the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your query, but there is something wrong with your error reporting. For example, the following line:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){//echo 'index failed'; var_dump($result);}
```

Will dump the `$result` variable when the SQL query returns **at least 1 row**. Perhaps you meant to use:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) { echo 'index failed'; var_dump($result); }
```

Also, some notes of caution:

1. Don't store passwords as plain text. http://alias.io/2010/01/store-passwords-safely-with-php-and-mysql/
2. Don't use `mysql_*` functions; they're deprecated. Look at [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).
3. Your code is wide open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 1):

change it

```
mysql_selectdb($db, $connect);
```

as

```
mysql_select_db($db, $connect);
```

Comment: according your code connection not create so no query was run

Comment: Why? If his DB connection does not work, he'd get `no`: `if(!$db_connect){echo 'no';}`

Comment: @BenM : You will try i think you will get no : statement. according to my knowlage

Answer (score 0):

There is a error in the syntax

```
$result = mysql_select($query, $connect);
```

Instead of the above code replace with this code

```
$result = mysql_select_db($query, $connect);
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is some error in your Syntax ,
Try to use

```
mysql_num_rows($result) or die('Could not Show result: ' . mysql_error());
```